# Do you need a config file when using User Property Settings

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, application-settings, settings

Is there a need to have a config file when using User Settings? I tried creating both User and Application settings then using them both in my code (including saving a change to the User setting). Then I deleted the config file and ran the .exe

Low and behold User Settings work just fine without the config file. So do Application Settings. Their initial values are taken from what was set in the Settings.settings designer.

However, the Application Settings can't be changed without the config file (meaning a config is needed for connection strings and installation setup), but for a smaller application with no installation needed we shouldn't really have to make the user change the config file themselves for setting changes.

As for the User Settings, their changes are saved to a separate config file stored in Local AppData...

So for these circumstances is a config file needed when using these settings?

```
Properties.Settings.Default.UserTitleColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

[image]

Comment: And what's the point of this question? You can do one thing in different ways, each way has pros and cons, so you choose the best fit to your requirements. Options are a good thing.

Comment: @Racil Hilan, "What's the point" may have sounded a little harsh. I've edited my question a little and changed it to "Is there a need".

Comment: I see, so you're basically asking if the global config file is required for .Net projects? No it isn't.  If you don't need any global settings for your app, then you don't need a global config file. Simply delete it from your project, it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

The config file is there to change the defined (default) values during compilation.
You are right that if the file is not there, the values are taken out of the assembly and the values defined at compile-time are used.
But to be able to change them without re-compilation the config file can be used.
A default use-case for that is connections-strings to databases: They are often in the "Application" scope, but need to be changed for each installation.

Comment: Thanks, but yeh I get that. Big applications that are distributed that require installation setup not done by the end user. But for a smaller application which just needs settings that can be changed using a GUI for the user. Is there any need for a config file? No database to connect to, no connection strings needed.

Comment: @DaoSeeker If you don't need it, don't use it ;-)